# Symfony2 - Use a personal function in an Entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity called Photo. A photo has a date field and I would like to format that date to relative time (example: "2 minutes ago" instead of "2012-01-23 01:45:00").
I found a function to do that, now I would like to know where and how I should call this function ?

I thought I could do that directly in the getDate() of my entity.
I created one service with my function to format date but then i realize that I can not access the "container" in an Entity. ($this->container->get('datehelper'); won't work.)

How should I process then ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundle you want: [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle).

If you want your own implementation, create a dedicated bundle (or insert it in a general bundle like "CommonBundle"), create your DateTimeFormatter class, and create your twig extension. You can of course inspire yourself from the KnpTimeBundle.

Comment: I installed the KnpTimeBundle but when I try {{ time_diff( photo.date ) }} it outputs "diff.ago.hour" in my template... What am I doing wrong ? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @hypete you need to turn on translations http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration

Comment: I have anoter last question, can I use time_diff in my controller ?

Comment: Try this in a controller: $this->get('time.datetime_formatter'), it is the defined service for the datetime formatter.

Comment: @Nanocom Thanks, it works fine :) 

For info, here's what I did :

$now = new DateTime();
$dateFormatter = $this->container->get('time.datetime_formatter');
$myNewDate = $dateFormatter->formatDiff($myDate, $now);